# Unable to decrypt disk on normal Lubuntu boot

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox, password

I'm having trouble starting up my system. I use VirtualBox to run Lubuntu 14.10 on Mac OS X 10.10.1 host.

I have used the built-in disk encryption available when installing (L)Ubuntu. When it boots after a normal shutdown or reboot, it prompts me for my password but I cannot input anything, I've tried to just type and hit enter but nothing happens. Screenshot below.[image: First password prompt]

I then proceed with a hard shutdown or reset and boot again. This time I am prompted to chose what I want to do. Screenshot below.[image: Boot choice]

Once I've chose to boot Ubuntu from this menu, it proceeds to prompt me for my password again. At this point I am able to input the password, the input is echoed back to the screen in the form of asterisks, and it continues starting up. Screenshot below.[image: Second password prompt]

The questions are:

- Is the first password prompt normal? As it looks quite a bit different from the second prompt.
- Can I set it up in such a manner that I am inmediately able to type my password.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not taking your input?. In Unix-like-world passwords are not usually echoed to the screen in any way, not even with circles or similar character (at least in console mode), people coming from other systems usually expect some kind of feedback. Have you tried just to type your password and hit enter?

Comment: @JavierRivera, I did try to type my password and hit enter, and unfortunately nothing happened. The odd thing is, the password in the second prompt is echoed to the screen with asterisks.

Comment: I got the same Problem with Ubuntu 14.10 and VirtualBox 4.3.20. I can't type the password in the box. I tried to switch to another tty and there was nothing. Switching back I got a black screen with the characters I wrote. I was able to write the passphrase and press enter, but nothing happend... The hard shutdown is the only solution I found :(

Comment: I have this problem with Ubuntu 15.04 directly installed on a machine (NOT inside VirtualBox). My workaround is to select "Advanced options for Ubuntu", then recovery mode, and then resume normal boot. Not sure what made this problem appear.

Comment: Same problem Ubuntu 15.10, kernel 4.2.0-26. If I remove "quiet splash" from  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in grub settings things work.

Comment: same problem with 16.04